# error bound of $I=\int_{0}^{1}\left(f'(x)\right)^{2}dx\thickapprox h\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\frac{f(ih)-f((i-1)h)}{h}\right)^{2}$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, approximate-integration

let for $f\in c^{3}$ and $I=\int_{0}^{1}\left(f'(x)\right)^{2}dx\thickapprox h\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\frac{f(ih)-f((i-1)h)}{h}\right)^{2}$.
whereas  $h=\frac{1}{N}$
find the maximal error bound in [0,1]. meaning find a term depends only on f derivatives.
what is the algebric accuracy of the bound?
My try: I tried to write f as interpolation of f(ih), and take the derivative, I got very nasty terms. Does someone has an intelligent solution?
The following question might be helpful to find the bound:
[Prove that $\int_a^b (f'(x))^2dx - h\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)}{h}\right)^2 = O(h^2) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3070153/prove-that-int-ab-fx2dx-h-sum-i-0n-1-left-fracfx-i1-fx)

Comment: I'm confused how the error is $O(h^2)$ since $h\rightarrow \infty$ should imply the error goes to zero.